# partition harddisk in already installed windows to dual boot windows/ubuntu without reformat

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Is it possible to partition my hard disk on my already installed Windows, and yet not reformat my hard disk in order to do so? And then still being able to install ubuntu to the second partition so that I can dual boot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No format of your hard disk should be needed

If you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, then all you have to do is tell the Ubuntu installer to install to the second partition

At most the Ubuntu installer would format the second partition to EXT4

Comment: But the problem is that ubuntu can't seem to detect my OS. Which is kind of frustrating.

Comment: Is your system Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, or 8.1?

Comment: Windows 7 actually.

Answer (score 0):

There are several partitioning tools and methods to achieve what you desire. I have used a good few but the one that comes to mind is Partition Wizard and here is a link discussing exactly what you want: -

http://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/repartition-windows7-drive.html

AFAIK, its free.

As always - Just in case of accident, create a system restore point, Do a backup, and have a recovery/boot CD/usb handy.

Finally, think about your dual boot as you might be missing one op/sys after the new install. Do a google of "LILO dual boot windows and ubuntu" to checkout your options.

Best of luck!